# How to recursively run through a tree, creating nodes, calling functions, and dive deeper?

Tags: java, loops, recursion

currently I am trying to develop an AI for a game similar to chess where I basically try to calculate a few steps ahead then to get the best possible payoff with alpha beta.

Currently my strategy is to , for every 1 move, make 4 best outcome moves, change "board" temporarily, then for those 4 moves, call 4 more again, then run the moves, call 4 more per each move.....

This seems very natural for a recursive function, I am trying to dig all the way down 10 moves or so. But so far I've wrote 3 steps (my turn, your, mine) and my code is already blowing up. I need to code the part where FOR EACH new move, calculate new move. Are there anyway I can truncate the below code so it can be something like recursive Call( ...) with a max level check as base case?

Here is my current iterative 3 - step code, assume there is a tree structure, inside every move contains an arraylist of 4 best counter moves.

```
 for (i = 0; i < root.children.size(); i++) {
        root.children.get(i).runStrat();
        root.children.get(i).printNode();
        for (int lvl1 : root.children.get(i).currOtherPieces) {
            root.children.get(i).addChild(lvl1,root.children.get(i).level + 1);         
            }
        for (j = 0; j < root.children.get(i).children.size(); j++) {
            root.children.get(i).children.get(j).runStrat();
            System.out.print("    ");
            root.children.get(i).children.get(j).printNode();
            for (int lvl2 : root.children.get(i).children.get(j).currSelfPieces) {
                root.children.get(i).children.get(j).addChild(lvl2, root.children.get(i).children.get(j).level + 1);
            }
            for (k = 0; k < root.children.get(i).children.get(j).children.size(); k++) {
                root.children.get(i).children.get(j).children.get(k).runStrat();
                System.out.print("            ");
                root.children.get(i).children.get(j).children.get(k).printNode();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I can keep writing 7 more layers of for loop, but maybe there is a clever way to recursively put this. Any help? Thanks!

(The sys.out with spaces are just for me to debug, can leave that out...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what are you doing is so called "behaviour tree traversal" or "solution space search", i.e. enumerating all the possible next moves and evaluate them. Behaviour tree traversal is just an application of [tree traversal methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

While a suggest you to get a good knowledge of breadth first tree traversal and deep first tree traversal strategies, I can give you a quick answer to your question.

When dealing with tree traversal, you might prefer iterative algorithm to recursive ones, as you can have troubles with stack overflow if you are not doing tail recursion optimization.

When traversing a tree you should use a queue, called "fringe", that contains the next nodes to visit.

```
Queue<Node> fringe = new LinkedList<Node>();
```

At first the fringe will contain only the root node.

```
fringe.add(root);
```

Then, you can iterate over the fringe, in this way:

```
while(fringe.isEmpty() == false) {
  Node current = fringe.poll();

  // Evaluate the current move, e.g. if it leads to an improvement of your gameplay
  boolean result = doSomething(current); 

  if(result && !current.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
     fringe.addAll(current.getChildren();
  }
}
```

This algorithm is a trivial implementation of the BST (Breadth First Traversal), which means you visit al children of a given tree level before move to the next. The DFS (Deep First Traversal) version uses a FIFO data structure for the fringe.

```
Stack<Node> fringe = new LinkedList<Node>();
fringe.push(root);

while(fringe.isEmpty() == false) {
  Node current = fringe.pop();

  // Evaluate the current move, e.g. if it leads to an improvement of your gameplay
  boolean result = doSomething(current); 

  if(result && !current.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
     for(Node child: current.getChildren()) {
        fringe.push(child);
     }
  }
}
```

There are a ton of optimisations of these two algorithms, such as ones that process children with different order according to some metrics (heuristic methods, such [A star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)), others that keep track of already visited nodes to avoid cycles, and so on.

To get a better grasp of solution space visit, I suggest you a reading of ["Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach" by Stuart Russel and Peter Norvig](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136042597).

For keeping count of the deepness of your search you can extend the Node object with a field called level, that for root is 0. When exploring node's children, before insert them in the fringe, just set their level at parent's level + 1, and if this is greater than your max level, just avoid to put them in the fringe.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I translated what you have to recursion:

```
public static void dive(final int maxDives) {
    dive(root, 0, maxDives);
}

public static void dive(Node current, final int level, final int maxDives) {
    for(Node n : current.children) {
        n.runStrat();
        n.printNode();

        if(level < maxDives) {
            for (int lvl : n.currOtherPieces) {
                n.addChild(lvl, n.level + 1);
            }

            for(Node m : n.children) {
                dive(m, level + 1, maxDives);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't know the type of your nodes, so I just put in `Node`.